# neo4j client doesn't support DNX 50

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm moving my web application to ASP.NET 5, my application is using Neo4jClient to connect to neo4j database.

But, one thing I see that neo4j client 1.1.0.40-DT doesn't support DNX50. 
I wonder if there are any alternatives or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the GitHub repo https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/135 at the bottom you'll find links which you can try. This is the only Core client for .net for neo4j, but I've had no feedback yet as to how it works.